# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while instrumenting eclipse rcp application

Tags: java, classloader, javassist, javaagents, bytecode-manipulation

I tried injecting a method call statement using javassist in every method of some desired classes. **The statement corresponds to a class in the java-agent jar. For example if my agent has class like a.b.HelperClass, I am injecting a.b.HelperClass.call(); in the beginning of every class using javassist.**

I tried with a spring boot web app and the agent works fine but with RCP application it is throwing

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.HelperClass
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Do I need to load the classes residing inside agent-jar using the eclipse class loader? **BTW I'm instrumenting by calling agent-main method and not premain**.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is OSGi based and has a module system that is enforced.

The HelperClass must be in the classpath of the Eclipse Plugin where it should be used.

Comment: Is there any other way to do so? Moreover does instrumentation api provides some kind of listeners where I can find when a particular method has been called under which thread (without using debugger api)?